# Why does it give this error when there is a column with this name?

Tags: python, pandas, group-by

```
df = pd.read_csv(r"fb441e62df2d58994928907a91895ec62c2c42e6cd075c2700843b89.csv")
max1 = df.groupby('Date').agg({'Data_Value':np.max})
print(max1['Date'])
```

```
raise KeyError(key) from err KeyError: 'Date'
```

I want to print the values of Date column

[image]

Comment: The original `df` dataframe has a Date column, but `max1` does not.  Print `max1` and you will see.

Comment: might be looking for `.reset_index()`

Comment: You are storing the result into `max1` variable. you can write `max1.reset_index(inplace=True)`. then when you call `max1['Date']` you'll be able to see the result.